# Multiple common prefixes among different paths

Tags: python, path, prefix, prefixes

Sorry for the title, my problem is as follows. I have a list of paths and I want to get *multiple* common prefixes. For example, given I have:

```
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_name-0.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_name',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_name-0.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO',
 '/usr/bin/pkg_name']
```

I want to have:

```
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_name-0.1-py2.7.egg/',
 '/usr/bin/pkg_name']
```

Because the first two have a common prefix that is a directory. Hope I made this clear,

rubik

EDIT: The paths I have are Python eggs and some executables. I want to remove the entire egg, not the directories inside it, like `EGG-INFO` or `pkg_name`. So it has to be `/usr/.../dist-packages/pkg_name-0.1-py2.7.egg/`. The other path, since it is an executable remains as it is.

Thank you

Comment: How the algorithm can tell it should not be just `/usr` ?

Comment: See my edit. It has to be a Python egg.

Comment: Why not just remove paths that contain `.egg/` in them?

Comment: Well, it could be dangerous...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not well-defined. What do you want to have in this case:

```
/usr/bin/a
/usr/bin/b
/usr/etc
/usr/local
```

Shall it be one `/usr` or two: `/usr/bin` `/usr`, or three?

In either case, the algorithm will be like this:

1. sort the list
2. take the first element and do `os.path.commonprefix()` with 2nd, 3rd, ..., i-th until common prefix is not `/`; that will be your first group
3. repeat step 2, starting from (i+1)th

Comment: Thank you. I know it is not well-defined, but I don't know how to explain it. I want to have common prefixes that are directory. So in your example it would be: `/usr/bin, /usr/etc/, /usr/local`. But the problem is more defined than that. The paths I have are Python eggs and their executable. I want to remove the entire egg, not the directories inside it (like `EGG-INFO` or `pkg_name`). I should edit my question...

Comment: I would suggest `os.path.commonpath()` for this operation, not commonprefix. It seems like the behaviour OP wants (and that I want having found this question with a similar use case), is to get the longest possible common path that matches more than one path in the list. So in this case it would be: `['/usr', '/usr/bin']`